# PGSQL: SORT isnt executed with rollup having only one result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having this code:

```
SELECT "monat", 
       CASE 
         WHEN count("erstkontakt_reaktionsdauer") < 3 
            THEN null 
         ELSE round(round(count("erstkontakt_reaktionsdauer"),2) / nullif(count("erstkontakt_reaktionsdauer"),0), 4) 
        END, 
        count("erstkontakt_reaktionsdauer") 
FROM "schema"."tablename" 
WHERE "monat" IN ('2021-04-01') 
  AND "monat" IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY rollup(1 ) 
HAVING count(*) >= 1 
ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST
```

While this worked all along, When I have more than one month in

```
 WHERE "monat" IN ('2021-04-01')
```

When I have only one inside the WHERE, the ROLLUP NULL isnt coming first

[image]

[image]

Comment: The query you're showing us has `NULLS LAST`, not `FIRST`. Either that's a typo in the question (in which case you're showing us a query you've never run and don't know what it actually produces) or you're not running the code you thought you were.

Comment: you're right, i fixed it. i tested in pgadmin if it changes in NULLS FIRST. ITs null first which makes problems. NULLS LAST works as expected

Comment: I started explain - If there's only one result SORT isnt executed, regardless of the rollup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a temporary table works

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT "monat", CASE WHEN count("erstkontakt_reaktionsdauer") < 3 THEN null ELSE round(round(count("erstkontakt_reaktionsdauer"),2) / nullif(count("erstkontakt_reaktionsdauer"),0), 4) END, count("erstkontakt_reaktionsdauer") FROM "schema"."table" WHERE "monat" IN ('2021-03-01') AND "monat" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY rollup(1 ) HAVING count(*) >= 1 
) t ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST
```

The Problem is, when there is only one result of the query (Rollup isnt counted), the SORT method isnt called. Using a temporary table solves this.